# How to handle software buttons Android

Tags: android, android-layout, button

Just in case: I'm pretty new in android so NO expert!

I have a question over the "software buttons" from some devices.

When i create a layout XML the buttons what are aligned to the bottom are behind these software buttons. How do i handle that the buttons always showed above the software buttons if there are some (the layout fits between top of the screen and the top of the software buttons) and the layout goes to the bottom of the screen when there aren't software buttons.

I looked for a solution @ google but can't find a simple and working solution (maybe i don't have the right google terms for it...).

---

**Update**

i tryed to draw what i mean....

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of you're trying to achieve and what is your current output ?

Comment: Done, i added a illustration of my problem.

Comment: I fixed the problem with adding: `android:layout_weight="1"` on some places. Now automatically the view fits between the top of the screen and the soft navigation bar. Thanks for your answers people.

Answer (score 4):

If you add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your XML layout your content should appear above the software navigation bar.

**EDIT:**

Try adding these lines to your styles.xml file within your `BaseTheme`.

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

Comment: I tryed to add this to the framelayout where the fragment is loaded in and i tryed to add this on the fragment root view. For me it sounds as a solution (fitsSystemWindows) but it isn't. I cant see any difference with before adding the property.

Comment: Try the edit, if it fails try stating false for translucent navigation instead, you shouldn't need to set the layout weight on your content, doing that will mean you'll have to add that line on everything which would be a pain. There must be something wrong in your styles.

Comment: It seems a bit of a hack, you don't want to be appending `android:layout_weight="1"` to every layout you create. But if your OK with that then fair enough. :)

Comment: Its only a project for school so at the moment i don't care. In future projects i will do it on the right way ;-). Thanks for your explanation, i'am sure i will need this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code in your activity on create:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the soft keyboard? If it is, add this on the activity in your manifest that you want this to happen.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"> </activity>
```

or

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>
```

or in your onCreate method:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: Not the keyboard but the navigation buttons some smartphone manufacturers use instead of the hardware buttons.